# Secret code receiver does not working on Samsung devices

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, samsung-galaxy

I wrote standart code for secret codes broadcast receiver. It works fine on all Android devices besides Samsung smartphones (Galaxy S5, Galaxy Grand Prime).

Android Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SecretCodeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />

        <data
            android:host="4568"
            android:scheme="android_secret_code" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Using Samsung special permissions has no result.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.factory.permission.KEYSTRING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.testingsettings.permission.KEYSTRING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.app.servicemodeapp.permission.KEYSTRING"/>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: have you got this answer?

Comment: No, I have not. I used phone number interception instead.

Comment: have you any example for that?